# Extract data out of experimental data

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, analysis, functions

After some experiment, I have a table of data with two variable. 
Such as $A = f(x1,x2)$.

How can I have a table of data like $x_1 = f(A,x_2)$ ?

I want to use this table in MATLAB 2D-lookup table.

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: This entails solving for $x_1$. This is a highly nontrivial task.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What has your question to do with `functional-analysis`?

Comment: Well, if you need a table you can just swap $x_1$ and $A$ columns.